# getline() returns an error

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to read from a file and use `strtok()` to break up the strings I get in from the file. The problem is, I keep getting this error whenever I compile the program.

```
source.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
source.cpp:39:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(char [1000], int,     char)’
source.cpp:39:32: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/stdio.h:675:20: note: __ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)
/usr/include/stdio.h:675:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char   [1000]’ to ‘char**’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2734:5: note: template<class _CharT, class    _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&    std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,   _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:1070:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&   std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,   _Alloc>&, _CharT)
```

Here is the portion of my code that is causing the problem.

```
char *p, line[1000], opcode[9], arg1[256], arg2[256];

int i = 0;

while(getline(line, 1000, '\n') != NULL)
{
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
    cout << "Line = " << line << endl;

    if (strchr(line, '#'))
    {
        *p = '\0';
    }
    if (p = strtok(line, "\t"))
        strcpy(opcode,p);
    if (p = strtok(NULL, "\t"))
        strcpy(arg1,p);
    if (p = strtok(NULL, "\t"))
        strcpy(arg2,p);

    printf("opcode=:%s: arg1=:%s: arg2=:%s:\n",opcode,arg1,arg2);

}
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

Comment: Is your code really C++? Looks like pure C to me.

Comment: By the way, where is your stream? Show us more code!

Comment: As you might have figures out by now there are several (at least three) functions called getline. There are two in the C++ iostream library, and there is one in POSIX. You need to say which one you are trying to use. The code looks like it's the POSIX one, but then why have you tagged your question C++?

Answer (score 0):

You call the `getline()` function completely wrong. See the manual for `getline()` on how to use it. You get a hint:

```
candidates are:
__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
getline(&line, 1000, your_file_pointer)
```

Comment: When I looked up the C++ resource over at cplusplus.com it said it showed that the prototype is istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );

Comment: So I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thanks for your quick reply btw.

Comment: In that case, you probably are missing an #include, as this is referring to C's `getline()` function from `stdio.h`

Comment: @cadavid4j: The signature you quote is a **member** of `std::istream`, i.e., you need to provide an object when using it, e.g.: `std::cin.getline(buffer, 1000);`.

Comment: @cadavid4j You've managed to confuse yourself (and people here) over the several different functions called getline. Please make it clear which version you are trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a stream to the file before you can start writing to it.

[Here is a tutorial on how to do it.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)